# How can I fix this code to show 10 seconds and hide 10 seconds again and again forever?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I fix this code to show 10 seconds and hide for 10 seconds again and again forever but seconds never stop when the visitor visit my website if code is in 5 or 3 or ...  seconds of showing he can see if the code is on 5 ose 4 or ... seconds of hide he can't see.

```
<div id = "adsdiv">This ad will close in 
<span id = "closingtimer">10</span>
seconds
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeMyAd() {
    document.getElementById("adsdiv").style.display = "none" ;
}

var seconds = 10;

function display() { 
    seconds --;
    if (seconds < 1) {
        closeMyAd();
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById( "closingtimer" ).innerHTML = seconds ;
        setTimeout("display()", 1000);
    }
}

display();
</script>
```

This code shows just 10 seconds and close.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it so that you have a timer variable that is constantly growing. It is keeping track of the current time in seconds. Every time it updates (once a second) you divide it by ten and then apply the `modulo` operator to the result to see if it is even or odd. Then, you have a looping if statement that, say, hides it if it's odd and shows it if it's even. That would make it flash once every ten seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.Hope it help you.

```
var hidden = true;
function close() {
    document.getElementById("adsdiv").style.display = "none" ;
}
function display() {
    document.getElementById("adsdiv").style.display = "block" ;
}

setInterval(function(){if(hidden) 
  {display();
   hidden = false;
  }else{
  close();
  hidden = true;
  }}, 10000);
```

Comment: Bro is very good but everytime when the visitors open then after 10 sec it close and again after 10 it show but what i can't do is seconds never stop when the visitor visit my website if code is in 5 or 3 or ... seconds of showing he can see if the code is on 5 ose 4 or ... seconds of hide he can't see.

Comment: What's your "if code is in 5 or 3 or ... seconds of showing he can see if the code is on 5 ose 4 or ... seconds of hide he can't see"  means?

Comment: bro this 5 or 3 seconds  is from function display()  time or function close() but this code doesn't work when no one is online this code start to work when website is reloading ? I want the same code just to work everytime if you open the site it will be in 7 second or any other seconds.
Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: It's about detecting whether the user is online,not related to the code above.